# ionic 2 edit table not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing a ionic 2 app where inside a form a editable table which have one submit button to submit data.how can we submit the data using one submit button of table and form data in ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
This is just an example of HTML and TS file and how to use it:

```
<ion-content padding>
        <ion-input type="text" #username></ion-input>
        <ion-input type="password" #password></ion-input>
        <button ion-button (click)="sendlogin()">Login</button>
</ion-content>
```

Than in TS:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',

})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(your declarations) {
  }
@ViewChild('username') uname;
@ViewChild('password') pass;
sendlogin() {
    Here goes your request to api with parametars this.uname.value and this.pass.value
  }
```

Comment: thanks I am new in ionic can you please elaborate the answer

Comment: I have edited the answer and formulated it as an example.

Comment: thanks but this is the process how to submit a form in ionic 2.My problem is in template there is a multiple textbox within a form along with some textbox. so how can i submit this data using one submit button. in ionic 2.

Comment: For each input, set it's own #something and they will all be submited with only one submit button press. In my example, there are only two, but you can add 10 or 20 more if you want such as field about me etc. Also, why don't you post your code so we can get a better picture of what you want to do.